# Node Sass Unsupported runtime error when building a Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I get this error message when I try to build my Next.js project; what is the problem?

```
> (base) net-MS24:~/Documents/myproject$ npm run build

> myproject@1.0.0 build
> next build

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
Loaded env from /home/xxxy/Documents/myproject/.env
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://err.sh/next.js/built-in-css-disabled

info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

./pages/content/_index.scss
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (/home/xxxy/Documents/myproject/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918)
```

Comment: What's your Node.js version?

Comment: version 10.19.0

Comment: I'd recommend moving to an LTS version of Node.js, like version 14.